# Unexpected behavior with jquery "on" events

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

**The Setup:**

```
handlerA & handlerB listen for event1, while handlerC listens for event2
```

**The execution:**

```
1. event1 is sent (handlers A & B are listening)
2. handlerA receives it, and along it's codepath sends event2
3. handlerC receives event2
4. handlerB receives event1
```

Question: If the 'on' event is supposed to be asynchronous, shouldn't handlerB receive event1 before handlerC receives event2?  Can someone explain this to me?

```js
console.clear();

window.EventDispatcher = {
  send: function(type, payload) {
    $(EventDispatcher).trigger({
      type: type,
      payload: payload
    });
  }
};

//---- SEND EVENT ----
$(function() {
  $('#sendEventBtn').on('click', function() {
    console.log('sending event1 to A and B...')
    EventDispatcher.send('event1')
  })
})

$(EventDispatcher).on('event1', handlerA);
$(EventDispatcher).on('event1', handlerB);
$(EventDispatcher).on('event2', handlerC);

function handlerA() {
  console.log('handlerA received event1');
  console.log('handlerA sending event2');
  EventDispatcher.send('event2')
}

function handlerB() {
  console.log('handlerB received event1');
}

function handlerC() {
  console.log('handlerC received event2');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='sendEventBtn'>Send Event</button>
```

Here's a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ux0kL3d5Hul8IopUXeRW?p=preview

Comment: misconception that `on()` is asynchronous

Comment: The word you are looking for is "non-blocking" & that is not "unexpected" behaviour, if the event2 from handlerA gets fired first then obviously handlerC would gets it first, its all about timing. In short, If by the time JS engine reached the line 4 if the handlerA has already finished then handlerC would receive the event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word you are looking for is "non-blocking" & that is not "unexpected" behaviour, if the event2 from handlerA gets fired first then obviously handlerC would gets it first, its all about timing. In short, If by the time JS engine reached the line 4 if the handlerA has already finished then handlerC would receive the event.

```
function handlerA() {
    console.log('handlerA received event1');
    console.log('handlerA sending event2');
    EventDispatcher.send('event2')
}
```

> sending event1 to A and B...
>
> handlerA received event1
>
> handlerA sending event2
>
> handlerC received event2
>
> handlerB received event1

Now have some delay(read more about [setTimeout with 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful)) for event 2 & you would see.

```
function handlerA() {
    console.log('handlerA received event1');
    setTimeout(function(){
       console.log('handlerA sending event2');
       EventDispatcher.send('event2');           
    }, 0);
}
```

> sending event1 to A and B...
>
> handlerA received event1
>
> handlerB received event1
>
> handlerA sending event2
>
> handlerC received event2